# Works in R but not in RMarkdown

Tags: r, dataframe, transactions, arules

I'm using R package `aRules` in order to make some tasks based on association rules for a dataset.

When I get my dataset, each variable is categorical so, I convert all of them in `factors`. My dataset is a `data.frame`. At the time I want to turn it into a *transaction set*, there is no problem and I can plot the `itemFrequencyPlot()` and so on.

My problem comes when I want to print the results into a PDF. I'm using `rmarkdown`. When it executes the following line:

```
my.df <- as(my.df, "transactions")
```

Everything explodes and I get:

```
Error in as(my.df, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing "data.frame" to "transactions"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> as
```

So, my questions are: Why can't I execute orders that works in R in RMarkdown? Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you included `library(aRules)` in your Rmarkdown?

Comment: Thank you so much, @LyzandeR. I don't know how I've forgot include it. That was!

Comment: Yep. Typical error :). Imagine how many times I ve made the same mistake to be able to call it without seeing the code :P